# Change Default Calendar Alert

Tags: macos, high-sierra, ical

Calendar's default alert sends a text message, but I prefer email. Setting an email alert requires several extra mouse actions. Is there a method to change Calendar's default behavior?

macOS 10.13.6, Calendar 10.0

Comment: I'm not clear with what you're asking...are you saying that the (obvious) way to do this requires too many extra mouse actions and you're looking for another way?

Comment: @Allan That's right. It's four mouse actions every time I set a calendar event and want a reminder. This isn't the end of the world, but it is annoying. I wondered — I'm not a programmer — if there were some Terminal command that might change this default behavior.